# Display a percentage in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to display a percentage to the user at the end of my exam. Essentially I need a line of code that divides myScore by the total amount of questions which is 70. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Here is my code for the end of the exam:

```
NSInteger endOfQuiz = [theQuiz count];
if((((questionNumber - 1) * 6) + 6) == endOfQuiz)
{
    // Game is over.
    if(myScore >= 49 )
    {
        NSString *finishingStatement = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Practice Exam concluded. Congratulations, you have passed with a 70%% or better! \nYou scored %i out of 70!", myScore];
        theQuestion.text = finishingStatement;
        answerResult.text = @"";
        counterLabel.text = @"";        }
    else
    {
        NSString *finishingStatement = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Practice Exam concluded. Unfortunately, you have failed with less than 70%%, keep practicing! \nYou scored %i out of 70.", myScore];
        theQuestion.text = finishingStatement;
        counterLabel.text = @"";

    }
    theLives.text = @"";
    answerResult.text = @"";
    // Make button 1 appear as a reset game button
    restartGame = YES;
    [answerOne setHidden:NO];
    [answerOne setTitle:@" Try this Practice Exam again" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with `float percentage = 100 * (float)myScore / 70;"? (You multiply by 100 to get the percentage.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The division operator in c (and thus Objective-C) is `/`.

```
myScore * 100 / 70
```

Comment: Looks like `myScore` is probably an integer, so your expression will also produce an int. Try casting `myScore` to `float` or simply changing the `70` to `70.0`.

Comment: This will work even if it's not a floating point number. Since we multiply by 100 first, the division by 70 will produce the whole number portion of the percentage.

Comment: Thanks! I knew there was a simple answer. And Caleb, you are right as well. Appreciated it guys.